# Is there a way to use the string literal type in an interface of object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a type `Color`,

```js
type Color = 'yellow' | 'red' | 'orange'
```

And I have an object which interface is `ColorSetting`.

```js
interface ColorSetting {
  id: string
  yellow?: boolean
  red?: boolean
  orange?: boolean
}
```

I want to use the type `Color` to simplify interface `ColorSetting`.

The code I simplified is below:

```js
interface ColorSetting {
  id: string
  [k in Color]?: boolean
}
```

But I got an error about `A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.`

How should I use the string literal type correctly in an interface?

Comment: I got a solution `type ColorSetting = {
  id: string
} & {
  [k in Color]?: boolean
}`, which is useful for me.

Comment: yes, an intersection is one way to do this.  Maybe you should post this as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, which is useful for me. This solution uses an [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types).

```js
ColorSetting = {
   id: string
 } & {
   [k in Color]?: boolean
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it important to use a string literal there? Would an enum with string values not suffice:

```
enum Colors {
  YELLOW = 'yellow',
  RED = 'red',
  ORANGE = 'orange',
}

interface ColorSetting {
  id: string;
  color: Colors;
}
```

The only downside to this approach is if you would ever need to reverse map this, which typescript doesn't do itself.

I tend not to use literals like this myself, so I'm not sure if this works, but give it a try:

```
interface ColorSetting {
  id: string;
  color: Color;
}
```

Basically just use your type as you've declared it, drop the '[k in Color]' bit